# Canonical line bundle over a projective bundle

Tags: vector-bundles, projective-space, grassmannian

The following is an excerpt from the Atiyah's K-Theory.

> If $E$ is a vector bundle over $X$ then each point $a\in P(E)_{x}=P(E_{x})$ represents a one-dimensional subspace $H_{x}^{*}\subset E_{x}$. The union of all these defines a subspace $H^{*}\subset p^{*}E$ where $p:P(E)\rightarrow X$ is the projection. It is easy to check that $H^{*}$ is a sub-bundle of $p^{*}E$. In fact, the problem being local we may assume $E$ is a product and then we are reduced to a special case of the Grassmannian.

In the statements above, $P(E)$ denotes the projective bundle associated to $E$. I am having some difficulty with the last statement about the Grassmannian.

Comment: Being a (sub)bundle is a local condition: we have to check it for an arbitr. small nbhd $U$ of an arbitr. point $a$. Over this nbhd the vector bundle $E$ is trivial.

Comment: Yes, I agree. What I am having trouble with is relating it to the Grassmannian.

Comment: if r is the rank of E then, is the rank of P(E) = r-1??

Answer (score 1):

(Small caution: Algebraic geometers call the bundle $H^*$ the *tautological* bundle; the *canonical* bundle refers to the top exterior power of the cotangent bundle. When I was a student, topologists were coming around to this convention as well.)

Presumably Atiyah means that to understand the tautological bundle of a projective bundle $\mathbf{P}(E)$, it's enough (locally) to understand the tautological line bundle over a projective space (a.k.a., Grassmannian of lines).